# Auto Executing Script For linux?

Tags: linux, scripting, executable

My Actual Problem was to auto execute a sh file to another host and return that output in my system. Is this possible??

"" I've to execute file @ host2 and get write input @ host1 ""

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH:

```
piskvor@host1$ ssh piskvor@host2 "/home/piskvor/myscript.sh" > myscript.out
```

What I did here: from `host1`, I opened a SSH connection as `piskvor` to `host2` and used it to execute `/home/piskvor/myscript.sh` (assuming it exists and I can run it). The output is redirected to file `myscript.out` at `host1`.

If you need password-less login, look into [SSH keys](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/).